# Check whether a div or one of its children were clicked

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a div as follows

```
<div class="parent">
    <!--several child divs now-->
</div>
```

Now, I have registered a click handler on body using AngularJS as follows:

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-click="registerClick($event)">
</body>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.registerClick(e) {
   //Here check if the parent div or one of its children were clicked
}
```

How, can use `$event` in my handler to determine if the div with class 'parent' or one of its children were clicked?

Comment: do you have jQuery in the project

Comment: Why are registering your click handler on the body and not the div itself? You can have as many handlers as you want. You really shouldn't be rolling out your own click handler that checks what element was actually clicked. Let angular do it for you.

Comment: yes, but I would still prefer a solution in angular, plain javascript if possible.

Comment: @Tarun see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/95w5b9m6/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
$scope.registerClick(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('parent')){
        // The .parent div is clicked
    } else if (e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('parent')){
        // Some child of the .parent div is clicked
    } else {
        var elem = e.target;

        while(elem.tagName != 'body' || !elem.classList.contains('parent')){
            elem = elem.parentNode;
        }

        if (elem.classList.contains('parent')){
            console.log('DIV .parent')
        } else {
            console.log('Body tag reached. No .parent element found');
        }
    }
}
```

`e.target` is the clicked element. Use it to determine which element was clicked. This is a **clean JavaScript solution**. You wont even need the `$scope.registerClick(e) {` part if can attach the event like so:

```
someDiv.onclick = function(){/* Same code as above. */}
```

if you use the latter approach, 'this' points to the `div`, so you can that the validations a little bit.

Comment: this is working only for the immediate parent. Any idea how to traverse all the parent nodes?

Comment: @Tarun I edited my answer. Check it out and test it, because currently I have to way to test it

Comment: Thanks! that was what I was looking for :)

Comment: @Tarun no problem. Just be sure to test it :)

Comment: yes, i get the idea of traversing all the parents until I reach body, so it will work no problem!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.registerClick = function($event) {
    //if has jQuery
    if ($($event.target).closest('.parent').length) {
      console.log('clicked parent');
      $scope.jQuery = true;
    } else {
      $scope.jQuery = false;
    }

    var isParent = false;
    if (angular.isFunction($event.target.closest)) {
      isParent = !!$event.target.closest('.parent');
    } else {
      var tmp = $event.target;
      do {
        isParent = tmp.classList.contains('parent');
        tmp = tmp.parentNode;
      } while (tmp && tmp.classList && !isParent);
    }
    $scope.native = isParent;
  };
})
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController" ng-click="registerClick($event)">
    <div>outside</div>
    <div class="parent">
      parent
      <div>div</div>
      <div>div</div>
    </div>

    <div>
      jQuery: {{jQuery}}
    </div>
    <div>
      native: {{native}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```